# How can I smooth an array in R?

Tags: r, spline

I have a 2-D array in R which represents value data for a grid of rows and columns.  It looks like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    2    1
[2,]    1    5    6    3
[3,]    2    3    2    1
[4,]    1    1    1    1
```

I want to "smooth" these values.  At this proof-of-concept point, I am fine with using any popular smoothing function.  I am currently attempting to use the `smooth.spline` function:

```
smooth.spline(x, y = NULL, w = NULL, df, spar = NULL,
              cv = FALSE, all.knots = FALSE, nknots = NULL,
              keep.data = TRUE, df.offset = 0, penalty = 1,
              control.spar = list())
```

by (naively) calling

```
smoothed <- smooth.spline(myarray)
```

When I run this, I get this error:

> Error in smooth.spline(a) : need at least four unique 'x' values

My array has four or more unique values in each dimension, so I am thinking that I do not know how to properly format the input data.  Can someone give me some pointers to this kind of thing?  The examples for `smooth`-like functions seem to work with single-dimension vectors, and I can't seem to extrapolate to the 2-D world.  I am an R novice, so please feel free to correct my misuse of terms here!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To do 1-d smoothing in either the vertical or horizontal axis, use apply:

```
apply(myarray,1,smooth.spline)
```

or

```
apply(myarray,2,smooth.spline)
```

I'm not familiar with 2-D smoothing, but a quick experiment with the fields package seemed to work.  You will need to install the package `fields` and it's dependencies.  Where `myMatrix` is the matrix you had above...  (I recreate it):

```
# transform data into x,y and z
m = c(1,1,2,1,1,5,6,3,2,3,2,1,1,1,1,1)
myMatrix = matrix(m,4,4,T)
myMatrix
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    2    1
[2,]    1    5    6    3
[3,]    2    3    2    1
[4,]    1    1    1    1
Z = as.vector(myMatrix)
XY=data.frame(x=as.numeric(gl(4,1,16),Y=as.numeric(gl(4,4,16))
t=Tps(XY,Z)
surface(t)
```

Produced a pretty plot.

Answer (score 8):

*Smoothing* is a big topic, and many functions are available in R itself and via additional packages from places like [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org).  The popular book '*Modern Applied Statistics with S*' by Venables and Ripley lists a number of them in Section 8.1:
(I think -- my 4th edition is at work) and Figure 8.1:

- Polynomial regression: `lm(y ~ poly(x))`
- Natural splines: `lm(y ~ ns(x))`
- Smoothing splines: `smooth.splines(x, y)`
- Lowess: `lowess(x, y)` (and a newer / preferred method
- ksmooth: `ksmooth(x, y)`
- supsmu: `spusmu(x, y)`

If you install the [MASS](http://cran.r-project.org/package=MASS) package that goes with the book, you can run this via the file  `scripts/ch08.R` and experiment yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `fields` package (https://github.com/NCAR/fields) and especially the very helpful vignette: https://github.com/NCAR/fields/blob/master/fieldsVignette.pdf