# R: How to have nice intersections between multiple wireframes (lattice)

Tags: r, lattice, wireframe

Given the following R code:

```
require(lattice)
x <- c(1:10)
y <- c(1:10)
g <- expand.grid(x = 1:10, y = 1:10, gr = 1:2)
g$z <- c(as.vector(outer(x,y,"*")), rep(50,100))
wireframe(z ~ x * y, data = g, groups = gr)
```

The intersection of the resulting surfaces is ugly, since it follows the grid-lines.

Is there a way to make the intersection between the surfaces look nicer (besides increasing the resolution of the grid)? Maybe by passing some parameters or using another package for visualization?

Comment: "Ugly" is subjective. :-) .  But yeah, you'll have to increase the resolution, unless someone knows of a package that applies a spline before drawing a 3D grid.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since I couldn't resist goofing off, here are a few possiblities for ways to smooth your data.

The package `scvm` appears to have some 2D model-fitting tools.

The `fields` package is recommended here:   [How can I smooth an array in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121484/how-can-i-smooth-an-array-in-r)

The `DiceKriging` package is reviewed here:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13510/fitting-multivariate-natural-cubic-spline